# Assert List contains only one instance of a class using AssertJ

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

Could I somehow use AssertJ to assert a List has only one instance of a (sub)class?

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C extends A {}

@Test
public void test() {
  List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
  list.add(new B());

  Assertions.assertThat(list).containsOnlyOnce(B.class);
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with your current code?

Comment: AssertJ's containsOnlyOnce method does not accept Class as it's argument. (unless the list was a list of Class.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a [Condition](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Condition.html).

Following will assert that `list` contains only a single object reference of type `B.class`.

```
Condition condition = new Condition() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object o) {
        return o.getClass() == B.class;
    }};

Assertions.assertThat(list).areExactly(1, condition);
```

It will fail for following cases:

```
list.add(new B());
list.add(new B());
```

and also for

```
B b = new B();
list.add(b);
list.add(b);
```

Using the Java 8 Stream API it can be achieved like

```
long countOfClassB = list.stream().filter(t -> t instanceof B).count();
Assertions.assertThat(countOfClassB).isEqualTo(1L);
```

Answer (score 24):

There is a method [hasOnlyElementsOfType(Class)](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#hasOnlyElementsOfType(java.lang.Class)), which verifies that all elements in the Iterable have the specified type (including subclasses of the given type).

The solution could look like:

```
assertThat(list).hasOnlyElementsOfType(B.class).hasSize(1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future. Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem

Comment: The call to `hasSize(1)` is not needed as `hasOnlyElementsOfType` already checks this.

Comment: `hasOnlyElementsOfType()` checks only type of the items, but items can be more then one. @timomeinen

Comment: Thank you @MarcinGołębski, you are right. It only checks for not 0, but indeed we want to be sure it is exactly 1.

Answer (score 15):

I would use AssertJ [extracting feature](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#extracted-properties-assertion) as is:

```
assertThat(list).extracting("class")
                .containsOnlyOnce(B.class);
```

Comment: Castigliola this is an amazing answer. Thanks for the lib.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that the type of `list` is `A`,
but the type of the element you're trying to verify with `containsOnlyOnce` is `Class<B>`.

You need to use corresponding types.
For example, you can extract the classes in the list:

```
Stream<Class<?>> classes = list.stream().map(x -> x.getClass());
Assertions.assertThat(classes).containsOnlyOnce(B.class);
```